# Git | Restore Unadded Files At Commits Times

Tags: git

TL;DR: I didn't add files, pushed updates and now I can't see the files in previous commits - I want to restore them.

What happened:
When I committed one time, I forgot to add them to the index, and then reverted back to a previous commit.

Is there a way to restore those files, via a `diff` or something? When git tries to commit while there are unadded files in the repository, what happens to those files? Does Git save information about them anywhere? Does it save *them* anywhere? Does it completely delete them?

I'm working on Visual Studio code and I've got GitLens, in case they can be of use.

Update: I think that I found that those untracked files were saved as either dangling blobs or unreachable objects. I'm currently checking this direction.

Comment: A Git commit consists of whatever is in the _stage_ at the time you commit (and not the working directory).  So, if you had other files in the process of being edited in your working directory, then just committing by itself won't involve them, and they should still be there.  But, your situation is complex, because you have "reverted" to a previous commit.  I don't know if that means you reset, or just applied a revert commit.  But in any case, you should give us the _exact_ steps you took here, if you want to get meaningful help.

Comment: if you didn't add files, you didn't commit them

Comment: @Alexan I know that they weren't committed - I thought at first they were.
In case it wasn't clear: at the time of committing I thought that they were going to be committed as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't remember entirely all the commands I used. I remember some, which I can add to the question.

Beyond that, is there any historical information that could be of use, such as the stages files at each commit time?

About the revert - if I remember correctly, I made commits without some files (forgot to add them), pushed it to a remote, and then pulled from the same remote. There is no mention of the files that weren't added in either the local or the remote branches.

Comment: Nothing you described actually sounds like a revert to me.  But, doing a pull could very well have wiped out your working directory, though it you were lucky, Git would have refused to do it, citing your working directory as the reason.  Do you remember any such warnings when you pulled?

Comment: It's not an actual Git revert - I "reverted" to a remote branch that was at all times either a copy or 1 commit before my local branch - I basically used the remote branch as a backup to my local branch. I think it gave me some conflicts, but I think that I used `--force` somewhere in there, perhaps when I pulled. Is it possible to see the list of all commands used on a Git directory to check what I did and what happened?

Comment: I do think it would be helpful to show the actual commands you used and hopefully their output as well?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It was about 2 weeks ago and I don't remember entirely what I did and I do not have their outputs. Is there any way to get any information about what happened there via Git? Maybe what commands were used, output logs, anything saved in the tree that might be useful?

Comment: AFAIK git does not keep a log of commands. Maybe look through your command history? (it won't give the results though) --- In bash I use `history`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

*Note: this does not restore file names.

1. Use `git fsck --unreachable` to get a list of all `unreachable` objects which displays for each object their SHA-1 ID.
2. For each object: use `git show <SHA-1 ID>` to read the contents of each object.
3. For each object: save the contents of the desired object into a file.
   Optional: try to guess the name of the file based on its contents.